# Is CSST piping and water piping in an inaccessible crawl space against code?

Tags: code-compliance, gas, crawlspace, csst

The CSST line that feeds our upstairs dryer with gas, the water pipes for the washing machine and some electrical wires run through an inaccessible crawlspace in the basement. When I went to turn the dryer on for the first time I smelled gas coming from the opening. After turning off the valve, I realized the area is not big enough to reach into, and I can't even see where the CSST line ultimately goes. I'm surprised neither myself or the inspector noticed this during inspection a month ago.

The home is located in Philadelphia in case that has implications on building code. The crawlspace shown in attached images *(Note: the CSST piping is white because the mold remediation company sprayed some mold-resistant paint on the joists.)* The opening is about 1 foot wide and maybe 6-8 inches tall.

[image: opening 1]

[image: opening alt angle]

[image: into the abyss]

I did some research on the gas line code, and from what I can tell this area may fall into the definition of a "concealed area" as defined in Section 404.5 of the IFGC International Fuel Gas Code (https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IFGC2012/chapter-4-gas-piping-installations). 
That section states:

> Portions of a piping system installed in concealed locations shall not have unions, tube fittings...

I can't be sure but I would imagine there is a union in there where the CSST connects to a valve in the floor.

Additionally this Philadelphia Gas Company (PGW) document states in Section 3.3 on P.16 (http://www.aspephila.org/_pdf/PGW%20Piping%202010.PDF):

> Minimum clearance of 4 feet should exist in the area where piping is located

and

> All piping should be installed in such a manner that it will be accessible for maintenance

To investigate and possibly have the gas line repaired, I am going to need to demo a portion of this wall to gain access to the gas, plumbing and electrical wires.

So my questions are:

1. Is this against code (gas piping, plumbing or electrical)?
2. If so, is there any way I can hold the home inspector accountable for missing it during the inspection?